# Accessing POJO Class in Spring

Tags: spring

I am new to Spring, Currently i am facing a difficulty to access a method of a  POJO class through another POJO class.

This is my JSON

```
[{
"name": "foo",
"albums": [
    {
        "title": "album_one",
        "artist": "foo",
        "ntracks": 12
    },
    {
        "title": "album_two",
        "artist": "foo",
        "ntracks": 15
    }
]},{
"name": "bar",
"albums": [
    {
        "title": "foo walks into a bar",
        "artist": "bar",
        "ntracks": 12
    },
    {
        "title": "album_song",
        "artist": "bar",
        "ntracks": 17
    }
]}]
```

This my classes

```
public class ArtistInfo {
     private String name;
     private List<Album> albums;

     public String getName() {return name;}
     public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;} 

     public List<Album> getAlbums() {return albums;}
     public void setAlbums(List<Album> albums) {this.albums = albums;}
  }

public static class Album {
   private String title;
   private String artist;
   private int ntracks;

   public String getTitle() {return title;}
   public void setTitle(String title) {this.title = title;}

   public String getArtist() {return artist;}
   public void setArtist(String artist) {this.artist = artist;}

   public int getNtracks() {return ntracks;}
   public void setNtracks(int ntracks) {this.ntracks = ntracks;}
  }
```

I want to access getTitle() method of Album Class through ArtistInfo class like:

```
ArtistInfo artistinfo = new ArtistInfo();
artistinfo.getAlbums().getTitle();
```

I know this was wrong because artistinfo.getAlbums() return a list it doesn't return object. If i add another field (Object for Album class in ArtistInfo ) it affect the Json format, if any way to acess getTitle() from artistinfo class or any modification in ArtistInfo class will help to acess it.

Please help me to solve this..........
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the titles of an artist you can use the following code

```
List<String> titles = artistInfo.getAlbums()
                .stream()
                .map(Album::getTitle)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```